# How can I rotate the screen on one view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, landscape, portrait

My app is under development as a hybrid app.

My question is how do I switch from the current view controller to vertical mode?

My main view controller is basically in vertical mode (fixed), and if necessary, I need to change it to horizontal mode.

Override this function and fix it in portrait mode.

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
          return .portrait 
}
```

Horizontal mode cannot be changed through the function below.

```
let value = UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect iOS device orientation change without rotating view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918095/detect-ios-device-orientation-change-without-rotating-view)

Comment: You need Transition not orientation. Bcz you are not change device orientation instead programatically changing orientation.So you have to play with VC.